# Ubuntu 16.04: Firefox comes up, but freezes

Tags: 16.04, firefox

I have Windows 10 as host. "Try Ubuntu" using Oracle VM Virtual box.
When I open firefox, the application comes up, but freezes. I have to Stop ubuntu all together.
Appreciate if you could provide me with steps to rectify this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not have given the guest OS enough memory in Virtualbox. Open the Virtualbox settings and set it to 2048 and retry Firefox... or boot directly to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if Firefox works OK for you.

Comment: I increased memory a bit, and it worked indeed.. hurray! Thank you very much :-)